Add AMD to Twilio dial.number?
I have this code running on my server. It is in the endpoint on my server that is specified in my TwiML app->Voice Configuration->Request URL. It works correctly, and the call is successful.
My question is, can I add automatic voice detection to it?
const VoiceResponse = require("twilio").twiml.VoiceResponse;

[.....]

try {
    const response = new VoiceResponse();
    const dial = response.dial({
        callerId: twilioPhoneNumber
    });
    dial.number(toNumber);
    console.log('TwiML: ', response.toString());

    // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(response.toString());
} catch (error) {
    console.log('/make-call endpoint: ', error);
    res.status(400);
}


Per their docs, it's a parameter on the create call api machineDetection = "Enabled"
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
const twilio = require("twilio"); // Or, for ESM: import twilio from "twilio";

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

async function createCall() {
  const call = await client.calls.create({
    from: "+18180000000",
    machineDetection: "Enable",
    to: "+1562300000",
    url: "https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16",
  });

  console.log(call.sid);
}

createCall();


Thanks! I figured that out, but now I've got this other anomaly, described in this SO post -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78773886/twilio-request-url-endpoint-returns-json-but-twilio-says-it-is-wrong-content-ty
