Twilio Request URL Endpoint Returns json, but Twilio Says it Is Wrong Content-Type?
My javascript web app is using Twilio Voice API.
I have this code running on my server. It is in an endpoint named "/make-call" It is in the endpoint on my server that is specified in my TwiML app->Voice Configuration->Request URL.
The code runs and the Twilio rings the phone of the callee. But on the client, a voice says "We're sorry, an application error has occurred." Looking at the Error logs on Twilio, I see:

Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL.
Please see Twilio's 
documentation on accepted content types  for more information on
valid Content-Types. You must return a Content-Type for all requests.
Requests without a Content-Type will appear in the
Debugger as a 502 Bad Gateway error.

But it appears that json is being returned. Here's a screenshot from the Twilio console:

What am I missing?
Here's the code from my /make-call endpoint:
console.log('/make-call. req?.body:', req?.body);

let nurseId = req?.body?.nurseId;
const navData = await getData(nurseId);
const toNumber = navData?.phone_1;
let nurseName = navData?.name_first;
const twilioPhoneNumber = Meteor.settings.private.twilio.phoneNumber;
console.log('toNumber:', toNumber);


try {
    const call = await twilioClient.calls.create({
        url: `${baseUrl}twiml`,
        to: toNumber,
        from: twilioPhoneNumber,
        // twiml: twimlString,
        machineDetection: 'Enable',
        AsyncAmdStatusCallback: `${baseUrl}handle-amd-result`,
        statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
        statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
        machineDetectionTimeout: 30
    })

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Call initiated successfully',
        callSid: call.sid
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Failed to initiate call',
        error: err.message
    });
}

...and just in case it is relevant, here's the code from my /twiml endpoint:
console.log('-----')
console.log('/twiml webhook. req?.body: ', req?.body)


//trying this out - start
const {VoiceResponse} = twilioClient.twiml;
const response = new VoiceResponse();

// Generate TwiML response
response.say('Hello, this is a response from your TwiML endpoint!');
response.play('http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3');

console.log('response.toString(): ', response.toString())
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(response.toString());


@jwallis, it would be great to get your input!

My guess is your amd status callback isn't returning a 200. Find the call in the logs and look at all the http requests. You should see the status callback request.

My console logs, as well as the Twilio call and error logs show that the amd status callback is not being hit.

Solved!
It appears that only xml is permitted as the content type. I updated my code to:
    let responseObject = {
        response: {
            success: true,
            message: 'Call initiated successfully',
            callSid: call.sid
        }
    }
    xml = xmlJs.js2xml(responseObject, xmlJsOptions);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    res.status(200).send(xml);

...and am no longer getting this error. Thanks, Twilio tech support, for this info.
